# Determining the Percentage of Uniswap V3 Trading Volume from Arbitrageurs vs Regular Traders

Tags: uniswap, exchanges, decentralized-exchange, defi, uniswapv3

I am trying to understand the trading dynamics on Uniswap V3. Specifically, I am interested in finding out what percentage of the trading volume on Uniswap V3 comes from arbitrageurs versus regular traders. This breakdown could further be divided into activity on correlated and non-correlated pairs, if possible.

AFAIK this information is not readily available on standard blockchain analytics platforms, such as Glassnode, Chainalysis, CoinMetrics, and Dune Analytics. Therefore, I am wondering if there is a way to deduce or estimate this breakdown from available on-chain data, or any other sources I might be overlooking.

For example, are there any specific on-chain patterns or markers that might indicate arbitrage activity? Or are there perhaps academic studies or papers that have researched this topic?